# How to upgrade nginx from 1.16 to 1.18 on centos7

Tags: nginx, centos7

I'd like to upgrade my nginx from version 1.16 to 1.18.

Belows were previous situation about nginx.

```
[root@localhost ~]# rpm -qa | grep nginx
nginx-mod-mail-1.16.1-1.el7.x86_64
nginx-1.16.1-1.el7.x86_64
nginx-filesystem-1.16.1-1.el7.noarch
nginx-mod-http-image-filter-1.16.1-1.el7.x86_64
nginx-mod-http-xslt-filter-1.16.1-1.el7.x86_64
nginx-mod-http-perl-1.16.1-1.el7.x86_64
nginx-mod-stream-1.16.1-1.el7.x86_64
nginx-all-modules-1.16.1-1.el7.noarch
```

Then I removed nginx version 1.16, and tried to install version 1.18 after registering nginx yum repository. And I found out that there are no dependent rpms needed for nginx 1.18

```
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package nginx.x86_64 1:1.18.0-2.el7.ngx will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

===================================================================================================================================
 Package                    Arch                        Version                                   Repository                  Size
===================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 nginx                      x86_64                      1:1.18.0-2.el7.ngx                        nginx                      769 k

Transaction Summary
===================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package

Total download size: 769 k
Installed size: 2.7 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]:
```

Is there no need to install below rpms for nginx 1.18? If so, are there any other additional rpms needed for nginx 1.18?

```
nginx-mod-mail-1.16.1-1.el7.x86_64
nginx-1.16.1-1.el7.x86_64
nginx-filesystem-1.16.1-1.el7.noarch
nginx-mod-http-image-filter-1.16.1-1.el7.x86_64
nginx-mod-http-xslt-filter-1.16.1-1.el7.x86_64
nginx-mod-http-perl-1.16.1-1.el7.x86_64
nginx-mod-stream-1.16.1-1.el7.x86_64
nginx-all-modules-1.16.1-1.el7.noarch
```

Answer (score 0):

yeo,
First you need to remove nginx from centos7:-

https://otodiginet.com/software/how-to-unistall-nginx-from-centos-7/

Then Download the nginx 1.18 in your server :-

https://centos.pkgs.org/7/getpagespeed-x86_64/nginx-1.18.0-1.el7.ngx.x86_64.rpm.html

**Installation Steps**

1. Install GetPageSpeed repository:

   yum install https://extras.getpagespeed.com/release-el7-latest.rpm
2. Install nginx rpm package:

   yum install nginx

Answer (score 0):

When switching from EPEL-packaged builds of NGINX to nginx.org (or getpagespeed.com) builds, *after* installing newer NGINX, you need to run:

```
yum remove $(yum list installed | grep 'nginx.*@epel' | awk '{ print $1 }')
```

This will remove any extraneous packages like `nginx-mod-stream`. They are not needed because their files and features are already included to the main package `nginx`.

Comment: Oh, so those packages are already included in main nginx 1.18 rpm. Thank you!